# g++ compiler hints to allocate on stack

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, stack-allocation

Are there any methods to give the compiler hints that some objects may have a more static behaviour, and allocate things on the stack instead of heap ?
For example a string object might have a kind of a constant size inside some functions.
I'm asking this because I'm trying to improve performance for an application by using OpenMP. I've already improved the serial part from going from 50 to 20 seconds, and it goes to 12 seconds with parallelism (mentioning that most of the code can be run in parallel). I'm trying to continue improvement. I think one limitation is related to continuous allocation and release of dynamic memory inside the same process.
The serial optimizations, so far, were related to merging to a more ANSI C approach, with a more hardcoded allocation of variables (they are allocated dynamically, but considering a worst case scenario, so everything is allocated once).
Now I'm pretty much stuck, because I've reached a part of the code which has a lot of C++ approach.

Comment: use local variables and types that don't dynamically allocate.

Comment: There are other types of memory allocation such as static allocation (e.g. with thread local store using threadprivate with OpenMP). You can also use memory pools instead of the heap. But your answer is too broad unless you show some specific and relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

The standard [std::basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) template (of which `std::string` is a specialization) accepts an allocator as its third argument, and you might supply your own stack-based allocator instead of [std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), but that would be brittle and tricky (you could use [alloca(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) and ensure that all the allocations are inlined; if they are not `alloca` won't work as you want it.). I don't recommend this approach.

A more viable approach could be to have your own [arena or region based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management) allocator. See [std::allocator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits)

You could perhaps simply use the C [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) on a large enough local buffer (e.g. `char buf[128];`)

Comment: I +1'ed because specializing the allocator indeed seems like the best way to reuse the Standard containers; however I would see about combining that with "small buffer optimization": use the stack buffer if big enough, and default to another arena or `new` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a small buffer optimization.
Detailed description can be found [Here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/common-optimizations/).
Basic idea is to add an union to the class, that will hold buffer:

```
class string
{
  union Buffer
  {
    char*    _begin;
    char[16] _local;
  };

  Buffer _buffer;
  size_t _size;
  size_t _capacity;
  // ...
};
```

Comment: This is of course already implemented in some `std::string` implementations.

Comment: Of course, but some compilers (for embedded systems for example) may not have this feature and if author is looking for low level optimizations it might help.

Answer (score 0):

so you are looking for deficiencies by using static analysis to find performance regressions?

It's a good idea, cppcheck has some of those, but those are very rudimentary.
I'm not aware of  any tool that does that so far.

There are however tools that do different things:

#### jemalloc

`jemalloc` has a allocation profiler. (See: http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/)
Perhaps this is of some help to you. I haven't tried it myself sofar, but I would expect it to post object lifetimes and the objects that produce the highest pressure on the allocator (to find the most hurting parts first).

#### cacheGrind

Valgrind has also a cache and branch prediction simulator. http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html

#### clang-check

if you find yourself having too much freetime you can try to run your own checking tools using `clang-check`.

#### google perftools

The google perf tools also have a heap profiler. https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/